# Trying to run my python script doesnt do anything

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for the vague title, but I am unsure how else to explain it. Running the command in terminal:

```
python --version
```

Outputs:

```
Python 3.9.10
```

When I try to run my `main.py` file using the command: `python main.py` or `python3 main.py` nothing outputs. I am new to Python and this was just working but I restarted my computer and now I cant get any of my Python scripts to output or run.

This is all that my `main.py` is:

```
def main():
    print("hello world")
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are you calling `main()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the function:

```
def main():
    print("hello world")

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the method. Just defining a method is not enough to run it.

Try this:

```
def main():
    print("hello world")

main()
```